# Expansion rate in matter dominated era

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion

Do physicists know what the expansion rate of the Universe was at the beginning of the matter dominated era?

Comment: Are you familiar with standard computations in cosmology involving e.g. the Friedmann equations?

Comment: I am familiar with the Friedman equations, but not calculating with them.  I was just curious if there was a consensus regarding what the expansion rate was at the radiation/matter transition and matter/dark energy transition.

Comment: many books on cosmology and/or GR (e.g. Carroll's book on GR) discuss these matters. Have a look around (outside Wikipedia ;) ).

Comment: When you ask for the expansion rate, are you asking for the Hubble constant?

Comment: @BenCrowell: yes, the Hubble constant